# Help me understand "mortal man never smoked their superior in quality."

Tags: meaning, context

I am a Korean reading *The Lives of the Great Composers* by Harold Schonberg.

There's part of an article quoted from the New York Times describing how Americans welcomed Offenbach in his visit to New York.

It goes:

> Reporters swarmed around him before he had yet landed, and one of
>   them, connected with a Tammany evening paper, was actually presented
>   with one of the great man's private cigars and testified with much
>   feeling that "mortal man never smoked their superior in quality.

What I am stuck with is the last sentence with double quotations. *"mortal man never smoked their superior in quality."* I really don't understand.

Does "mortal man" mean general human-being or the modest reporter who was presented with a cigar? What does "never smoked" "superior in quality"? Does it mean that the reporter was so honored that he forgot the superior quality of the cigar?

Comment: Yes, 'mortal man' means humans in general. The reporter meant that the cigar was so good that no-one had ever smoked a better one.

Comment: It's just normal advertising HyperBowlLIII.

Comment: Thank you, Kate and Hot Licks. You really helped me. Now I see it sounds like an advertisement. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence is basically saying "no man has ever smoked a better cigar."

"Mortal man" means all of humanity.  Meaning one would have to be a deity or of some other world to find a better cigar.

Please know that this is written somewhat poetically and you would never hear a native English speaker say something like this in casual conversation.  I had to read it in context in order to understand it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I realized for the first time that "never" can mean "have ever done something". It is grateful that you pointed out that it is not very easy to understand the sentence, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It simply is a way of saying 'there are no cigars better than that brand' i.e. they have no superior, so it is impossible to smoke a higher-quality cigar.

Re user's answer, personally I don't see a problem with the use of 'their', I just see it as the standard pronoun to use in the context.  As for the use of 'mortals', yes, it is referring to mankind as a whole.

Hope I've helped!

Comment: Thank you so much Lordology. It really helped me understand the sentence. Hope you have a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds awkward to me too. I think the word choice "**their**" makes it so.

I interpret that the reporter was referring to the cigar (**their brand quality**). Meaning that mortal man never smoked a more superior brand of cigar (because there are **none superior** available to be had by mortals - implying the divine).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm just interested in how you see 'their' to be the incorrect pronoun here?

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect. It only seems difficult (awkward - my words) to understand within the whole context of the passage. I suppose it was the word choice of the reporter.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put awkward.  But then how would you phrase if you did not use 'their'?

Comment: I would have used "a cigar" possibly or left the word out completely. Is this confusing in some way?

Comment: "mortal man never smoked a cigar superior in quality." sounds unidiomatic (or at least inferior to the original), especially since the word 'cigar' had been used in the immediate last sentence, and also for a writer of that time period. As for "mortal man never smoked superior in quality", this sounds unidiomatic even more so.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Actually, I googled the article and confirmed that it has been directly quoted from the original. I was also stuck with the pronoun "their". But now I see it would've not been a big trouble for me to understand the sentence if I'd known that "never" could mean "have never".

Comment: @user22542 Thank you very muuch for your analytic explanation. I can now understand the meaning and also see how the implication makes the sentence sound dramatic. Hope you have a great weekend! :)